# Thread.getContextClassLoader() == null?

Tags: java, classloader, contextclassloader

Can `Thread.getContextClassLoader()` be null ? The javadoc is not really clear.
Should a library take this case into account ?

Update: the reason I asked is that `beansbinding.dev.java.net` does *not* work in this case (and my code does `setContextClassLoader(null)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java threads created from JNI code in a non-java thread have null ContextClassloader unless the creator explicitly sets it.

Also in such context Thread.currentThread() returns null.

Comment: This can be fixed by setting
        
`ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);`

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should, someone could have called `Thread.setContextClassLoader(null)` and your library IMO should be able to deal with that.

Comment: That is a really nasty thing to do. Even classes from installed extensions wont be found with that thread context class loader.

Comment: I don't see why that would be nasty.