# NullPointerException trying to load a file

Tags: java, json, weblogic, jdeveloper

Scenario is the following:

- Developing a jsp application with jdeveloper
- Deploying to Oracle Weblogic
- All files are in the same project
- Source files are inside packages that are inside the `src` folder
- Inside the `Resources` folder are two files: `menu.json` and `TestWS.properties`

So, I made a java class that should read `menu.json` and return a menu (in html) based on its structure.

When, inside the class, I do this

```
InputStream i =
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
        getResourceAsStream("Resources/menu.json");
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));
```

The `InputStreamReader` constructor throws a `NullPointerException`, I suppose because it can't find the file.

Funny thing is, if I try to load `TestWS.properties` instead, it loads it just well.

I tried checking the project's properties, manually added both files under `Project Source Path -> Resources`, adding the `.json` extension to `Compiler -> Copy file types to output directory`, renamed, deleted, recreated, changed extension to the json file, deployed to WAR and loaded the project on another machine running weblogic, but to no avail.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Did you check that the json file is correctly exported in the war file (by decompressing it) ?

Comment: @dystroy actually no. I just checked and it doesn't. How do I include it? (I'm very very new to this kind of stuff...)

Comment: Thread.getContextClassLoader == null... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225594/thread-getcontextclassloader-null

Comment: @Luca if it was the case, it wouldn't load TestWS.properties

Comment: If you are building the WAR file with JDeveloper, there must be some option somewhere which makes it exclude the .json file from the war.

Comment: Can't find it, but if I move the json file to the public_html folder it seems to see it. When the web services are up again, I'll try again if it runs.

Comment: The file is there, but still can't read it, both trying to load "menu.json" and "/menu.json"

Comment: Take a look at http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/jdeveloper-controlling-which-resources-files-are-copied-into-the-projects-output-directory/

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks. Please post that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in [this article](http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/jdeveloper-controlling-which-resources-files-are-copied-into-the-projects-output-directory/).

In short, you have to change the compiler setting "Copy File Types to Output Directory" to include the extension of the resources you want to have available at runtime.